# Why does R say that a data set does not exist when I have assigned it and can see it in the project environment?

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and am having an issue with R identifying a new data set I created when I ask it to create an OR plot. Here are the steps I followed:

I created a new dataset that includes just the first observation using the below syntax. Please note that "df_full_dataset" was an excel file previously loaded into R.

```
df_first <- df_full_dataset %>%
group_by(PID) %>%
arrange(Obs) %>%
filter(row_number()==1)
```

Then, I ran a logistic regression using that data set (df_first). This ran successfully:

```
regression <-glm(indicator~age+gender,family=binomial,data=df_first)

summary(regression)
```

However - the issue arises when I go to create the OR plot. I used this syntax (found here: https://infoart.medium.com/making-an-odds-ratio-plot-in-r-5a2d88ea2817).

```
coef(regression)
 exp(coef(regression)) 
 exp(confint(regression))
 cbind(coef(regression),odds_ratio=exp(coef(regression)),exp(confint(regression)))

library(finalfit)

data(df_first)
iv = c("age","gender")
dv = "indicator"

df_first %>% 
or_plot(dv, iv,table_text_size = 3)
```

I get this error:

Warning message:
In data(df_first) : data set ‘df_first’ not found

I have confirmed that the data set exists:

```
exists('dr_first')
[1] TRUE
```

Edited: I am using RMarkdown to track my syntax. I have also tried to include all of the above syntax in the same chunk. This also did not work.

Comment: Hi @alexx. I would open a scratch RScript instead of an RMarkdown and go line by line to debug your code. The way it is written, you are creating `df_first` from another dataset called `df_full_dataset` but then further down you are calling a built in dataset named the same (your call to `data(df_first)`). I tried loading the finalfit package to find a built in dataset with that name and could not, but if there is one it would overwrite your first code chunk creating `df_first`. If you need more help clear your workspace and start from scratch, then provide the `dput(df_full_dataset)` in post

Comment: The `data()` function is designed to load datasets that have been included with a package; you don't need it for your own data.  It was probably used in a package example.  So just skip that line, and the rest should work (though I am not familiar with the `or_plot()` function, so you might still have problems there).

Comment: @user2554330 Entirely correct, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @user2554330! It worked when I removed that line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @user2554330. The data set did not belong in the data() function. The OR plot successfully ran when I simply removed that line of code. No additional changes were made to the syntax.

@user2554330 comment that answered my question: The data() function is designed to load datasets that have been included with a package; you don't need it for your own data. It was probably used in a package example. So just skip that line, and the rest should work (though I am not familiar with the or_plot() function, so you might still have problems there).